# How I can up the red message with CSS

Tags: css, xhtml, margin, space

The form is generated by Bootsface and I want the red message is near to the input. The HTML is in: http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/9590959sin-ttulo.png

The CSS code is:

```
#loginForm:inputUsuario, #loginForm:inputClave{
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

A XHTML fragment for the form is:

```
<h:outputLabel id = "txtUsuario" for = "inputUsuario" value = "#{msgs['loginForm.usuario']}"/>
<b:inputText id = "inputUsuario" required = "true" value = "#{logBean.nombre}" class = "inputText"/>
<h:message for = "inputUsuario" class = "text-danger text-center"/>
....
```

Is the space between `b:inputText` and `h:message` and I do not want this space

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML, including the red message.

Comment: Thanks. I worked with the class attribute.